# Laravel 5: How to use firstOrNew with additional relationship fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a CMS that allows the user to save and create bike tours. Each bike tour also has categories, which are definined using Laravel's Many to Many relationship utilising an intermediary pivot table. At the point of saving a tour, we don't know if the tour is an existing one being edited, or a new one.

I **think** I should be using Laravel's `firstOrNew` method for saving the tour, and the `sync` method for saving categories. However, all the tutorials very simplistically just give the example of passing a single object to the function like so:

```
$tour = Tour::firstOrNew($attributes);
```

But what happens when my `$attributes` also contains extra stuff, like the categories which are linked to a relationship table, and which I will need to save in the next step? For example [this very good tutorial](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2016/04/06/introducing-laravel-many-to-many-relations/http://) gives the following example:

```
$categories = [7, 12, 52, 77];

$tour = Tour::find(2);

$tour->categories()->sync($categories);
```

But what happens if the category data is bundled with the data for the rest of the tour, and instead of using `find` I need to use `firstOrNew` to create the tour? Should I keep the categories in the `$attributes` while I instantiate the tour, then run the `sync`, then unset them before saving the tour, or...? Is there a better way to achieve this?

**EDIT:** To be clear, the `$attributes` variable in my example here is essentially the tour object data bundled together- just as the Laravel/Eloquent system would return it from the transaction using the belongsToMany method- with subequent modifications from the user). ie: here is a snapshot of what it contains:

```
array (
  'id' => 1,
  'uid' => '03ecc797-f47e-493a-a85d-b5c3eb4b9247',
  'active' => 1,
  'code' => '2-0',
  'title' => 'Tour Title',
  'url_title' => 'tour_title',
  'distance_from' => 20,
  'distance_to' => 45,
  'price_from' => '135.00',
  'price_to' => '425.00',
  'created_at' => '2013-12-31 15:23:19',
  'updated_at' => '2015-07-24 16:02:50',
  'cats' => // This is not a column name!
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 7
  ),
)
```

All of these attributes are column names in my tours table, other than cats, which references another table via a hasMany relationship. Do I need to unset it manually before I can set this object class and save it with `$tour->save`?

I am looking for the cleanest *most Laravel* way to do it?

**EDIT2:** Here is the relationship defined in the Tours model:

```
class Tour extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function cats(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\TourCategory', 'tour_cat_assignments', 'tour_id', 'cat_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm getting your point. But since you dont mention about it... have you tried [hydrate](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrate) or [fill](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill) ?

Comment: Never heard of either of those, looks promising- thanks!

Comment: Keep us posted!

Answer (score 2):

you need to define $fillable property of your Tour model to tell eloquent which attributes to consider when using mass assignment so it will ignore categories related attributes silently. for ex.

```
<?php
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tour extends Model {
     protected $fillable = ['name'] //... other attributes which are part of this model only and laravel will consider only these attributes and ignore category related attributes which you can consider later use.
}
```

Comment: " it will ignore categories related attributes silently" No, I am getting a `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column` error for any and all attributes that aren't column names in the Model's db table.

Comment: make sure your fillable array consist of only columns that are available to tours table

Comment: I suspect you're just misunderstanding me. If I try to create and save a new object to the database which contains attributes that aren't column names, I get the column not found error. Putting a list of all the column names in the $fillable array makes no difference....

Comment: don't use DB object for insert if you use Model for insert it will consider the fillable property and only fill those values when mass assigned.

Comment: I am creating the appropriate eloquent model and calling save on it, ie: `$tour = new Tour($attributes); $tour->save();` If $attributes contains properties that aren't column names, I get the error- even when listing all the column names in the $fillable array within the Tour model. I am using Laravel 5.3.

Comment: er, OK my friend, I owe you an apology! I have no idea what was happening before, but this does indeed work! So you **must** explicity list all the column names in the $fillable array on the model (setting `$guarded = [];` doesn't work, so perhaps it was trommelaap misunderstanding me above)

Comment: when used $guarded those attributes won't be mass assignable, and it will throw error if you assign it, for ex. $guarded = ['id'] and now when you create model and pass id attribute it will throw error that id is not assignable. and $fillable is reverse of $guarded. if the answer helped you mark it correct so others can take help.. :) also don't use $guarded and $fillable both you should use one of them only at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firstOrCreate. The data actually gets persisted using this method.

```
$categories = [7, 12, 52, 77];
$tour = Tour::firstOrCreate($attributes)->cats()->sync($categories);
```

Got to make sure the fields are mass-assignable to be able to use the firstOrCreate method though. So either set the fieldnames in the $fillable property or put this in the Tour model:

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

Comment: No, sorry, this triggers a `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories' in 'where clause'`- which is the crux of my question; do I need to unset categories from the `$attributes` array first? As I said, all this data is bundled into $attributes (which is effectlvely the tour object, just as Laravel returns it from the database using the belongsToMany method- with subequent modifications from the user)

Comment: Please post the relation as defined in the Tour model

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned "CMS" and "subsequent modifications from user", I guess that you are getting your attributes from a `Form` which means you are getting a `Request` object/collection.
If that is the case then you can try

```
$tour = Tour::firstOrCreate($request->except('cats'));  
$categories = [];
foreach($request->get('cats') as $key=>$value){  
    $categories[] = $value;
}
$tour->cats()->sync($categories);
```

However, if your `$attributes` us constructed as an array (probably with some manipulations on form data) as per your **EDIT** then in that case you may try:

```
$tour = Tour::firstOrCreate(array_except($attributes, ['cats']);  
$categories = [];
foreach($attributes['cats'] as $key=>$value){
    $categories[] = $value;
}
$tour->cats()->sync($categories);
```

In any case, you must have the mass assignable fields declared in `$fillable` property in your model i.e. `Tour`.

Hope this helps.